# How to make a navigation which disappears while scrolling down but shows up by scrolling up?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I want to create a navigation bar that disappears when the user scrolls down the page but reappears when the user scrolls back up. Kind of like the search bar that is in the mobile chrome app. Does anyone know how to do so? All I have so far is a simple div that is fixed to the top.

[Here is an example](http://www.teehanlax.com/story/medium/) - the navigtion only appears when the user scrolls up a little bit.

Comment: What javascript have you tried so far? Please add it to the question.

Comment: @Joe all the java that I have tried so far has been deleted unfortunately.

Comment: Do you want the navigation bar to be hidden unless the user has scrolled back up to the very top of the page?

Comment: @MarcAudet no not the very top...i need it to act like a the chrome web browser on the iphone. you scroll up just a little bit to see the navigation

Comment: For a demo, is it okay to simply hide the navigation bar as you scroll down and then show it as you scroll up?

Comment: @MarcAudet i think so i placed an example in the question

Comment: @MarcAudet the link that I provided is exactly how I need it to act

Comment: The Guardian web page has this functionality. The header is "fat" on page load, and when you scroll down, it shrinks to a single line. When you scroll up, you can see the header again.
http://www.theguardian.com/guardian-observer-style-guide-a

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Prototype using jQuery

Here is one way you might do this.

Suppose this your HTML, fixed header and some content:

```
<div class="header">The header or navigation elements go here...</div>
<div class="main">
    <p>Some content...</p>
</div>
```

Your CSS might be:

```
.header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 9px;
    right: 9px;
    height: 50px;
    border: 1px dotted blue;
    background-color: rgba(125, 125, 125, 0.5);
}
.main {
    margin-top: 60px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    width: 25%;
}
```

The jQuery to make this happen is as follows:

```
$(window).scroll(
    {
        previousTop: 0
    }, 
    function () {
    var currentTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (currentTop < this.previousTop) {
        $(".sidebar em").text("Up"); /* optional for demo */
        $(".header").show();
    } else {
        $(".sidebar em").text("Down");
        $(".header").hide();
    }
    this.previousTop = currentTop;
});
```

Demo fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/Mar62/

**How This Works**

The trick is to compute whether your are scrolling up or scrolling down.  You can do this by storing the previous value of the `.scrollTop` position.

Define an anonymous JavaScript object with a single member to store the value:

```
    {
        previousTop: 0
    }
```

and pass that object to the jQuery `.scroll()` function.

When the window scrolls, get the current top position of the window scroll bar,
then compare it to the previous value, and then either show the header if
scrolling up or hide it if scrolling down.

After the show/hide decision, update the `.previoustop` with the `currentTop` value.

No other plug in required.  You can fade in/out the header or use some other animation instead of a simple show/hide.

Comment: thank you it worked. One question though, what if i wanted the header to disappear only after the height of the div has been passed? The problem I have is that it disappears right away and I am left with a white gap. Would I have jquery add a class or an attr after the window scroll reaches a certain point? If so how would I go about adding that?

Comment: If your header has a fixed height, it would be easy enough. Instead of `currentTop < this.previousTop`, you would test `currentTop - height-of-header < this.previousTop` or something like that.  I can check when I get back to the desk.

Comment: okay thank you. I tested what you wrote and it did not seem to work. So pretty much the header needs to stay where its at i.e. not be fixed until the height of the header is passed...then it becomes fixed...i think

Comment: I added a var headerHeight = 50; just below var currentTop = $(window).scrollTop(); and then wrapped the existing if statement in another one, so the scroll up/down hide and show effect only fires once you have scrolled more than the header height. Here's a codepen http://www.codepen.io/patrickwc/pen/jKlpr

Comment: Great solution! I modified this solution a little to create a smooth disappearance/appearance effect: instead of `$(".header").show()` I used `$(".header").css("opacity", "1");` , instead of `$(".header").hide()` I used `$(".header").css("opacity", "0");` and finally added the following to the css: `.header{ transition:0.7s; }` Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/o17z58of/

Answer (score 0):

you mean like g+ does it ?

you can use this plugin here ( https://github.com/brandonaaron/jquery-mousewheel ) to detect the mousewheel event and take action based on that

```
$('#my_elem').mousewheel(function(event, delta, deltaX, deltaY) {
    console.log(delta, deltaX, deltaY);
});
```

there is also a test page [here](http://brandonaaron.github.io/jquery-mousewheel/test/)

Comment: not really. I want the navigation to disappear when the user scrolls down but i want it to reappear when the user scrolls up just a little bit...not all the way to the top

Comment: you make that navigation div fixed and you use jquery to show() or hide() the div that you want, i've done it myself a while back all you need is this mousewheel plugin and the rest is simple logic...