# Create a disappearing header similar to the one found in Chrome for Android

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a mobile optimized website with a fixed header. I was thinking about implementing a disappearing functionality to the header in a similar manner as Chrome for Android.

The gist of the behavior is that when the user scrolls up the header gradually disappears with the content, and then gradually re-appears when scrolling up — unlike [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17136513/1344955)’s answer where the header appears/disappears completely.

My current header looks like this:

```css
@import url('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.8/css/materialize.min.css');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons');
header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
header nav {
  box-shadow: none !important;
}
#content {
  margin-top: 56px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #f5f5f5;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav>
    <div class="nav-wrapper">
      <a href="#" class="brand-logo">My Awesome Website</a>
      <ul id="nav-mobile" class="right">
        <li><a><i class="material-icons">settings</i></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>

<div id="content">
  <p class="flow-text">This is where the rest of the website&rsquo;s content should be</p>
  <br><br>
  <p>Don&rsquo;t mind me, just adding a few blank lines to make this scrollable&hellip;</p>
  <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
</div>
```

How can I implement this using jQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is fairly simple: store the scroll position, listen for the `scroll` event on `<body>` *(or, generally speaking, whatever your topmost scrollable container is)* and check if the position has increased or decreased, then perform the appropriate action (increase/decrease the header’s `top`).

The `Math.min` and `Math.max` are necessary to prevent the header from going flying across the screen in either direction. They limit the top value so that it's either hidden just above the viewport or pinned right at the top.

Here’s a working demo:

```js
(function($) {
  var $html = $('html'),
      $header = $('header'),
      lastScrollTop = $html.scrollTop();
  var disappearingHeaderHandler = function() {
    var scrollTop = $html.scrollTop(),
        headerHeight = $header.outerHeight(),
        headerTop = parseInt($header.css('top'), 10);

    $header.css('top',
      scrollTop > lastScrollTop
      ? Math.max(-headerHeight, headerTop - (scrollTop - lastScrollTop))
      : Math.min(0, headerTop + (lastScrollTop - scrollTop))
    );

    lastScrollTop = scrollTop;
  };
  $(window).on('scroll', disappearingHeaderHandler);
  disappearingHeaderHandler();
})(jQuery);
```

```css
@import url('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.8/css/materialize.min.css');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons');
header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
header nav {
  box-shadow: none !important;
}
#content {
  margin-top: 56px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #f5f5f5;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
  <nav>
    <div class="nav-wrapper">
      <a href="#" class="brand-logo">My Awesome Website</a>
      <ul id="nav-mobile" class="right">
        <li><a><i class="material-icons">settings</i></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>

<div id="content">
  <p class="flow-text">This is where the rest of the website&rsquo;s content should be</p>
  <br>
  <br>
  <p>Don&rsquo;t mind me, just adding a few blank lines to make this scrollable&hellip;</p>
  <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
</div>
```